# "Laid off" vs. "fired"

Tags: перевод

In English, we have 2 distinct words for describing the loss of a job

- Getting fired
- Getting laid off

The former implies that the action was the fault of the employee, while the later implies that the action was the fault of the company.

But when I was trying to translate `laid off` in Russian, the result it gave me was `уволен`, which is the same as getting fired.

Does this distinction exist in Russian? If you say `уволен`, is the context more like getting fired or getting laid off?

Comment: Not an "answer" (but I don't have reputation to comment); instead a tip. An alternative to using google translate as a starting point is [wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com). That has dictionary references, and also is annotated by human contributors. Until machine learning gets better, that may have results that are more reasonable. E.g., [http://www.wordreference.com/ruen/сократить](http://www.wordreference.com/ruen/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Уволить** - It is the verb that describes the action taken by the company, it does not actually specify whose fault it is.
**Был уволен** - Was fired by the company.
**Уволился** - Left the company by his own will.
**Уйти с работы** - Common expression for describing the situation when an employee leaves the company by his own will.

There is also **"отчисление"** - but this is suitable for education.

Comment: сокращение - вполне себе существующее слово

Answer (score 10):

For "laid off", Russian has the somewhat jargony-sounding, but very commonly used, **сократить**. It properly refers to staff cuts (**сократить штат**), which is why this "laid off" usage applied to a single employee (e.g. **меня сократили**) is slightly jarring for the inner purist, as well as a little absurd in the imagery it invokes, but that's still how you say it.

Comment: When you say "jarring for the inner purist", could you elaborate on what you mean by this? Also, could you please translate `сократить` in your answer. I was able to google it, but google translate is often wrong so it would help people like me who are still learning. Thanks!

Comment: @nmg49: technically, *сократить штат* means "to cut staff": the company was employing ten engineers and then made a decision to only employ five and let the other five go. It's a legal term with quite a strict meaning, besides other things. A layoff may be caused by other things: the company's license might be suspended, a decision was made to replace the workforce with cheaper and less qualified people, etc. A court would not qualify all that as a staff cut, however people who got laid off like this would likely use the word *сократили* when talking of termination of their employment.

Comment: And *сократили + smbd* is a metonymy, it's the staff size which gets cut, not the person.

Comment: @nmg49 I think *сократить (кого-то)* / *быть сокращённым* / *меня (её, их...) сократили* are just a colloquialisms. The more complete (as well as more correct) way of saying the same things would be *уволить (кого-то) по сокращению* / *быть уволенным по сокращению* / *меня (её, их...) уволили по сокращению* (also *…по сокращению штата*). Colloquial speech tends to use shorter forms of expression, hence we often say (and hear) just *сократить* / *сокращён* / *сократили*.

Comment: @nmg49: сократить is "to make (someone) redundant".

Comment: 'Сократили' Is not more or less of a colloquial expression than 'laid off'. It's a perfectly good translation. "To make redundant' is a British expression. It's not really used in the US or Canada.